# How to add features to the toolbar of any window ? (right click on toolbar)

Tags: toolbar

I am a retired Linux user and I am now only working on Windows 10. There is a super simple feature that I used a lot on Linux "Stay on top".

I don't understand why, but it's never been a feature on Windows whereas it is super useful especially when you program.

I tried a bunch of software to do that but none are as convenient as right click on the top toolbar of Windows 10 and select "Stay on top".

Is there a way using a script or something else to do this on my own ? I think it should be easy but I'm lacking english keywords to find this.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtiSJ.png

This is the link to an image showing the menu where I want the option to be. (I can't directly post it here :'( )

Thank you for your help, I hope I've been clear enough.

Comment: https://www.howtogeek.com/196958/the-3-best-ways-to-make-a-window-always-on-top-on-windows/ or if missing linux too much then https://www.dexpot.de/index.php?id=features; AFAIK it is free for personal use.

Comment: Hi Doc,
Thank you for your answer !
I've already been through those links (I read every first results from Google hahah) and I am even currently using dexpot right now.

But I'd really like to do it on my own. Dexpot has a lot of features I don't need.